# How do I solve $x+lg\left(5^x-1\right)<x\cdot lg\left(2\right)+lg\left(20\right)$

Tags: inequality, logarithms

$$x+lg\left(5^x-1\right)<x\cdot lg\left(2\right)+lg\left(20\right)$$
I've done:
$$
lg\left(x^{10}\left(5^x-1\right)\right)<lg\left(2^x\right)+lg\left(20\right)\\lg\left(x^{10}\left(5^x-1\right)\right)<lg\left(2^x\cdot 20\right)\\x^{10}\left(5^x-1\right)<2^x\cdot 20,\ 5^{x}>1
$$
and don't know how to continue

Comment: What base is $lg$.  I've usually seen as as $lg = \log_{2}$ in which case $lg(2) = 1$ so thid so simply $5^x - 1 < 20$ or $x < \log_5 19$.  If lg is base 10 (of any other base) you have $10^x(5^x-1) < 2^x+ 20$

Comment: Shouldn't that be 10^x and not $x^{10}$?  As log 10^x = x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what base $\lg$ is supposed to be $2$, $10$, $e$, some other number?

If the base is $2$ the answer is particularly nice.  $10$ is really nice too. Generic $b$ seems to get us nowhere. I'll show that and I'll show the base being $10$ and being a generic $b$.

$\log_2(2) = 1$ so

$x +\log_2(5^x - 1) < x\log_2 2 + \log_2 20 = x + \log_2 20$

$\log_2(5^x -1) < \log_2 20$

$5^x - 1 < 20$

$5^x < 21$

$x < \log_5 21 = \frac {\log_2 21}{\log_2 5}$.

For base $10$ we have

$x + \log(5^x - 1) < x\log 2 + \log 20$

$10^x(5^x - 1) < 2^x*20$

$2^x5^x(5^x -1) < 2^x*20$

$5^{2x} - 5^x < 20$

$(5^x)^2 - 5^x - 20 < 0$

$(5^x - 5)(5^x +4 ) < 0$

So one of $(5^x -5)$ and $(5^x +4)$ is negative and the other positive.  But $5^x + 4 > 5^x  -5$ so

$5^x -5 < 0 <  5^x + 4 > 0$ and $-4 < 5^x < 5$ so $0 < 5^x < 5$ and

$x < 1$

....

For base $b$ in general we get nowhere.

$x + \log_b(5^x-1) < x \log_b 2 + \log_b 20$

$\log_b b^x (5^x-1) < \log_b 2^x20$ (Note: you tried $x^{10}$.  It should have be $10^x$)

$b^x(5^x-1) < b^{x\log_b 2}20 $

as $b^x > 0$

$5^x - 1 < 20b^{(\log_b 2) - 1)x}$

$5^x - 20b^{(\log_b 2)-1)x} < 1$

$b^{x \log 5} - b^{\log_b 20 + x(\log_b 2 - 1)} < 1$

And that's about as far as I'm willing to go. We simply need to know some values of $5$ and $2$ in terms of $b$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: $$x=\lg(10^x)$$ and we get $$10^x\cdot 5^x-10^x<2^x\cdot 20$$ and after dividing by $$10^x>0$$ we get
$$5^x-1<\frac{20}{5^x}$$ set $$t=5^x$$ and solve a quadratic inequation

Comment: Is "lg" supposed to be $\log_{10}$?  Or $\log_2$ or some other base.